# Trying to simulate Thread behavior in orher class with Java

Tags: java, interface, java-threads

I have this class:

```
public class MyThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.print("Test from Anonymous Class!");
            }
        };
        Thread newThread = new Thread(thread);
        newThread.run();
    }
}
```

When i run this program, i get `Test from Anonymous Class!`.

Now, i'm trying to simulate this behavior with another class like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    public void doTest();
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public MyClass() {}

    public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {}

    public void doTest() {
        System.out.println("Test from MyClass!");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass() {
            public void doTest() {
                System.out.println("Test from Anonymous Class!");
            }
        };

        MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass(myClass1);
        myClass2.doTest();
    }
}
```

When i run this program, i get `Test from MyClass!`. Why is in the fist example printing out `Test from Anonymous Class!`? How can i get the same behavior with `MyClass` class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your second example doesn't make any sense. You create an anonymous class, but you don't use it. If you want to use it, call `myClass1.doTest();` instead. I don't know what kind of behaviour you're trying to simulate, but your example code isn't doing anything smart. You're passing a constructor parameter, but you're not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to implement a delegation from a class that takes as parameter of the constructor an interface.

The `Thread` constructor uses the `Runnable` instance provided as parameter as target of the execution when you invoke `Thread#start()` while your custom class doesn't mimic this behavior. You indeed do nothing with the `MyInterface` parameter passed :

```
public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {}
```

To implement a delegation, you should add a `MyInterface` field in `MyClass` and value it in the constructor.
Then use it in `doTest()` method.

```
public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {}

  private MyInterface myInterface;
  ...
  public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {
    this.myInterface = myInterface;
  }

   public void doTest() {
       // do some processing
         ..
       // then delegate
      myInterface.doTest();
   }
}
```

Comment: That's an example of an expert answer, thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: Completely understood. Thank you!

Comment: @Damian Lattenero  You are well kind.

Comment: @davidxxx. One more question please. But if you want to mimic that behavior, how can achieve this in my class? With other words, how to print `Test from Anonymous Class!` when using `MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass(myClass1);
` and `myClass2.doTest();`? The exact way that happens in the first example. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ioana  No problem :) Just don't change the code of the `Test `class you have posted. It is fine. The problem was is in the `MyClass` implementation.

Comment: @davidxxx Ok, I understand but what changes do I need to make in the second example to achieve the same thing as in first? To print the exact thing that `newThread.run();` is printing? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're doing Nothing with your param `myClass1`

```
public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {}
```

You get the parameter, so what? if you want to do what the parameter do, you must invoke the method:

```
myClass1.doTest()


>"Test from Anonymous Class!"
```

What you're doing is rare, but if you invoke the method from the correct object, you will get what you want :)

Another way, rare but valid, is to have an instance variable, and call it:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    MyClass myOtherClass;

    public MyClass() {}

    public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {
       this.myOtherClass = myInterface;
    }

    public void doTest() {
        System.out.println("Test from MyClass!");
    }
}
```

Then, you call the method inside it:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass() {
            public void doTest() {
                System.out.println("Test from Anonymous Class!");
            }
        };

        MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass(myClass1);
        myClass2.myOtherClass.doTest(); // calling method from myClass1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your target ,so it will call the method in your class

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
        MyInterface myInterface;
        public MyClass() {}

        public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {
            this.myInterface=myInterface;
        }

        public void doTest() {
            if(myInterface !=null){
                myInterface.doTest();
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Test from MyClass!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's it! I agree, it should initialize it! Just good for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. 
The run() method in Thread is overriden and it will always be the one to run.

In the second example myClass2 uses it instance doTest() method and myClass1 is never used, except in constuctor.

Comment: That's true, what do you think is the best way to get invoked the thread1 method?

Comment: I wouldn't expose the myOtherClass from myClass2. The mediator pattern has a somewhat similar idea of that I am suggesting.

Comment: I get it! Well thinked